# Extracting image from html in Android

Tags: android

I am able to parse html content using HTMLCleaner & able to populate in list view.  But extracting image I ma facing problem. while I am able to get images from any web server, i am not able to get same from my local Apache http server.

I want to know the reason & possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give your image tag ,without see its impossin\ble how to work with it...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the phone (emulator?) doesn't have access to your local server.

Use the browser in the phone/emulator and try to access your server just to make sure if it's this problem.

If you have access, print the url and make sure everything is alright.

Comment: I tried opening my emulator  by giving http://myip. But it didn't open. i don't know why it isn't taking  this format.